# Master Detail Flow While clicking on recyclerview I get null exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, master-detail

Well, I have recyclerView and a fragment as the examples of of Master Detail Flows
now i'm getting my data from json and i'm parsing it in the recyclerView perfectly
the problem is whenever I click on it I get null exception..

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
 */
private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
        // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
        // to load content from a content provider.
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.id);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detail, container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText("hello");


    }

    return rootView;
}
```

and this is the Activity

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own detail action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    // savedInstanceState is non-null when there is fragment state
    // saved from previous configurations of this activity
    // (e.g. when rotating the screen from portrait to landscape).
    // In this case, the fragment will automatically be re-added
    // to its container so we don't need to manually add it.
    // For more information, see the Fragments API guide at:
    //
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
    //
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
        // using a fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                getIntent().getStringExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        navigateUpTo(new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

this is where i get the json and ItemlistActivity

```
public class ItemListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
View recyclerView;
/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */
private boolean mTwoPane;
RequestQueue queue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

     recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.item_list);
    assert recyclerView != null;

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
        // If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
    }
    connection();

}

private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String profilePicUrl = mValues.get(position).profile_pic;
        String full_name = mValues.get(position).full_name;
        String state = mValues.get(position).state;
        String city = mValues.get(position).city;
        String phoneNo =  mValues.get(position).phone_no;

        holder.full_name.setText("Name : " +full_name);
        holder.state.setText("State : " +state);
        holder.city.setText("City : " +city);
        holder.phone_number.setText("Phone Number : " +phoneNo);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(profilePicUrl)
                .fitCenter()
                .override(500,500)
                .into(holder.profile_pic);




        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                    ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                    Log.e("hello",holder.mItem.full_name);
                    intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }


}

public void connection(){

    final String url = "aaaaa";

    // prepare the Request
    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // display response
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject test = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String gender = test.getString("gender");


                            String full_name = test.getJSONObject("name").getString("title") + " " +
                                    test.getJSONObject("name").getString("first") + " " +
                                    test.getJSONObject("name").getString("last");

                            String state = test.getJSONObject("location").getString("state");
                            String city = test.getJSONObject("location").getString("city");
                            String phone_no = test.getString("phone");
                            String profile_pic = test.getJSONObject("picture").getString("large");
                            String id = test.getJSONObject("id").getString("name");
                            Log.d("test2222", gender + " \n " + full_name + " \n " + state + " \n " + city + " \n " + phone_no + "\n" + profile_pic
                                    + "\n" + id);


                            addItem(new DummyContent.DummyItem(gender,profile_pic, full_name, state, city, phone_no,"hello"));
                        }                            

                        setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"check internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
    );

    // add it to the RequestQueue

    queue.add(getRequest);
}
```

and at last dummycontent

```
public class DummyContent {

/**
 * An array of sample (dummy) items.
 */
public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

private static final int COUNT = 25;

static {
    // Add some sample items.
}

public static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.full_name, item);


}



/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem  {
    public final String id;
    public final String profile_pic;
    public final String full_name;
    public final String state;
    public final String city;
    public final String phone_no;

    public final String data;



    public DummyItem(String id ,String profile_pic, String full_name, String state ,String city,String phone_no,String data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.profile_pic = profile_pic;
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.state = state;
        this.city = city;
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
        this.data = data;

    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return full_name;
    }
}
 }
```

now the thing is that I want to get same data (text or image) to the fragment
my problem is that I can't even show the fragment with custom "hello world" textview i get exception whenever I click on the recyclerview so explain to me where is the wrong in my code thanks

and this is the ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public final View mView;
public final ImageView profile_pic;
public final TextView full_name;
public final TextView state;
public final TextView city;
public final TextView phone_number;


public DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

public ViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    mView = view;
    profile_pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    full_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.full_name_txt);
    state = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.state_txt);
    city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_txt);
    phone_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_no_txt);


}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " '" + full_name.getText() + "'";
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure how SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter works, but Isn't the ViewHolder class required in recyclerview adapter where we initialize all the layout items?

Comment: I added the ViewHolder for you

Comment: little help please people

Comment: Are you able to see the list of data in recyclerView? Only clicking leads to Crash? I see that you are using View recyclerView instead of RecyclerView recyclerView. Also, have you assigned the Layout Manager to recyclerView like recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); ??

Comment: yes i can see the data but whenever i click on it i'm sending ARG_ITEM_ID with bundle the problem is with this it's always null although i'm giving data for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null value because you are using mItem from ViewHolder class without initializing, which is null.

Try this:

```
 DummyContent.DummyItem mItem = mValues.get(position);  //initialize here, not in ViewHolder class
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTwoPane) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, mItem.id); //use without holder
                ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                Log.e("hello",holder.mItem.full_name);
                intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, mItem.id); //same here

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: and 1 question is the id important in master detail flow or i can do it and add data without id and parse it how ever i want

Comment: It depends on how you are populating fields in Detail activity. It you are fetching data again from server in Detail, you just have to pass the id to get the particular record. Or you can implement Parcelable in your Model class and pass the whole Model class object to detail activity, where you can fetch the data from the received object without fetching the data from server again.